# __attribute__(packed) v/s GCC __attribute__((aligned(x))

Tags: c, gcc

Following GCC `__attribute__(packed )` will pack to byte boundary, aligned is used for which purpose  :--

```
u8 rx_buf[14] __attribute__((aligned(8)));  
struct S { short f[3]; } __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
```

above array will be of 16 byte, am I right.

means `sizeof(rx_buff)` will be 16 byte .. i.e 2 byte alignment at end

Comment: To answer your unasked question: no, you should not (and it is considered a bad practice) dump structures to disk or rely on memory alignment whatsoever, whether it is for internal program use or not.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. The `aligned` attribute does not change the sizes of variables it is applied to, but the situation is slightly different for structure members. To quote the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html),

> aligned (alignment)
>
> This attribute specifies a minimum alignment for the variable or structure field, measured in bytes. For example, the declaration:
>
> ```
> int x __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = 0;
> ```
>
> causes the compiler to allocate the global variable x on a 16-byte boundary.

and,

> packed
>
> The packed attribute specifies that a variable or structure field should have the smallest possible alignment — one byte for a variable,
>   and one bit for a field, unless you specify a larger value with the
>   aligned attribute.
>
> Here is a structure in which the field x is packed, so that it immediately follows a:
>
> ```
> struct foo
> {
>     char a;
>     int x[2] __attribute__ ((packed));
> };
> ```

Note that the `aligned` attribute may change the memory layout of structures, by inserting padding between members. Subsequently, the size of the structure will change. For instance:

```
struct t {
    uint8_t  a __attribute__((aligned(16))); /* one byte plus 15 as padding here */
    uint16_t b __attribute__((aligned(16)));
};
```

would lead to 15 bytes of padding after `a` whereas the default alignment for the target architecture might have resulted in less. If you specified the `packed` attribute for the structure **and** lost the `aligned` attributes the structure would have a size of 3 bytes.
Here's an illustration of how the memory layout of a structure **might** look like in each case.

`struct t` with no attributes and default alignment on 8-byte boundary:

```
+-+-------+--+-------+
|a|       |bb|       |
+-+-------+--+-------+
```

`struct t` when a and b are aligned on 16-byte boundaries:

```
+-+---------------+--+---------------+
|a|    padding    |bb|    padding    |
+-+---------------+--+---------------+
```

`struct t` when a and b have no alignment restrictions and t is packed:

```
+-+--+
|a|bb|
+-+--+
```

Comment: You're missing one effect of alignment - if `a` and `b` are aligned, there will be padding after `b` as well. This is because the size of `struct t` must be a multiple of 16 (otherwise, in an array, the second element will have its fields misaligned).

Comment: Also padding is added if a struct is aligned: say `struct foo {int a; int b;}` and `struct bar {int a; int b;} __attribute__((aligned(256)))` will have different size. `sizeof(struct foo) == 8` while `sizeof(struct bar) == 256`.

Answer (score 4):

> above array will be of 16 byte, am I right.

Incorrect. The array is still 14 bytes long; all that `__attribute__((aligned))` does is provide any necessary padding *outside the array* to align it to an 8-byte boundary. It is impossible to safely assume anything about where this padding exists, or how much of it there is.

As such, `sizeof(rx_buf)` will remain 14, just as it would have been without the alignment.